# how to run a program with no FormBorderStyle inside C# form?

Tags: c#

I want to learn how can i run a external program in my c# form.
with these speccifications:

```
FormBorderStyle = none
```

Size and Location fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run an external process within your own. You can start one, but it's gonna run on its own and you cannot access its internal behaviors. However, if your goal is to use a class (like a form) from another .exe or .dll, you can do it by referencing it in your solution and creating that instance like any other. But if that form is already controlling its own location, size and so on and doesn't allow to be modified, you're kinda stuck. You could force it with some reflection, but the behavior might be highly unpredictable.